# R programming for loop difference

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two columns i want to loop in such way it should calculate  arrival   of(i) -  departure of (i+1) and the value should store in a new column.

```
departure                            arrival
2012-01-26 08:15:00                 2012-01-26 08:50:00
2012-01-26 11:30:00              2012-01-27 16:00:00
2012-01-27 18:00:00               2012-01-27 23:05:00
2012-02-11 00:20:00                 2012-02-11 09:10:00

expected output
waiting time
(2012-01-26 08:50:00)-(2012-01-26 11:30:00) =  2 hr 40 min
 (2012-01-27 16:00:00)-( 2012-01-27 18:00:00) =  2 hrs
 (2012-01-27 23:05:00)- (2012-02-11 00:20:00)=14 days 13 hrs, 349 hrs
```

Please help in complete code for above data. In R I tried but there are some    errors

```
for (i :length(data frame){
i <- i[17] #index of arrival column
j <- i+1[18] #index of departure column
diff = i-j
return diff
}
diff = waiting time
```

There are some errors in calculating the difference in arrival and departure

I have converted the data departure and arrival by `POSXClt`

Answer (score 0):

This uses the package `lubridate`:

```
d$departure <- lubridate::ymd_hms(d$departure)
d$arrival   <- lubridate::ymd_hms(d$arrival)

d$difference <- d$departure - d$arrival
d
```

> ```
>             departure             arrival difference
> 1 2012-01-26 08:15:00 2012-01-26 08:50:00   -35 mins
> 2 2012-01-26 11:30:00 2012-01-27 16:00:00 -1710 mins
> 3 2012-01-27 18:00:00 2012-01-27 23:05:00  -305 mins
> 4 2012-02-11 00:20:00 2012-02-11 09:10:00  -530 mins
> ```

Comment: thank you, i need the difference between arrival ist value and departure second value i.e (2012-01-26 08:50:00)-(2012-01-26 11:30:00) which gives difference of 2 hours 40 mins